# Using Server in Mvc.Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have my own inherited `App.Controller` from `Mvc.Controller` which then all of my controllers inherit from. I wrote a provider utilizing an interface and implemented it as `MyService` and the constructor takes the `Server` property of `Mvc.Controller` which is of `HttpServerUtilityBase`.

However, I instantiate `MyService` in `App.Controller`'s constructor. The problem is that the `Server` property of the Controller is `null` when constructing `MyService`. I have used `public Controller () : base() { }` to get the base to be constructed. However, `Server` remains `null`.

I would like to avoid `Web.HttpContext.Current.Server` if possible.

Has any one have a work around for this problem?

**Edit:** Well, I have implemented tvanfosson's suggestion, and when my app constructs `MyService` in the property `get` method, `Server` is still null.

**Edit 2:** Nevermind, I was a goof. I had another `Controller` using `Server` aswell and did not change that. Case closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use delayed initialization to construct your service.

```
private MyService service;
public MyService Service
{
    get
    {
         if (this.service == null)
         {
             this.service = new MyService(this.Server);
         }
         return this.service;
    }
}
```

Then, your service isn't actually instantiated until it is used in the controller action and by that time the Server property has been set.

Comment: Or override Controller.Initialize, which fires at the right time.

Comment: The best part of delayed initialization is that it doesn't ever happen if the property is never accessed.

Answer (score 0):

> I instantiate `MyService` in `App.Controller`'s constructor.

There's your problem. You need to pass an instance of `MyService` which has already been constructed into your `App.Controller`'s constructor. Take a look at the Inversion of Control / Dependency Injection patterns, and take a look at some of the libraries which make these patterns easy ([see this list](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx)).

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is very pluggable, and you can either write your own ControllerFactory or use one from a library. I like Autofac, so I tell ASP.NET MVC to use Autofac's ControllerFactory. Autofac autowires the arguments to my controllers' constructors, and the constructors are free of all "dirtiness."

Comment: If constructing `MyService` requires `Controller.Server` then it can't be constructed before the controller you pass it to

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the Server reference? Are you doing stuff like url/html encoding? If so, you could use [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) instead and get rid of the context reference entirely.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but the subject is still relevant. So, one hint in 2017 that was possibly not available in 2009:

It is true that in the `Controller` constructor `Server` is null. But you can use the `OnActionExecuting` event:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) 
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    CurrentServer = Server; // CurrentServer is some instance variable I need later.
}
```

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](https://www.visionfriendly.com/blog/mvc-the-server-object-is-null-in-the-controllers-constructor/), if you have this Controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
  private string folderPath;

  public MyController()
  {       
    // Throws an error because Server is null
    folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/uploads"); 

    // Throws an error because this.ControllerContext is null
    folderPath = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/uploads"); 
  }
}
```

Then you want to initialize it this way:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
  base.Initialize(requestContext);

  // now Server has been initialized
  folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/uploads"); 
}
```